# Load Animator From XML without using Animator Controller Unity3d

Tags: c#, xml, animation, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

So, im building a simple project, i have to load an Animator from XML. all the animations, layers ,animatorVariables  and even transitions. it all working, all classes are OK, but when i try to build it it doesnt work(android), as i cant use UnityEditor in my build.

```
AnimatorController controller=new AnimatorController();
   /*add everything to the controller*/
someObject.runtimeAnimatorController = controller;
```

I havent found how to do this without `AnimatorController`, its possible? its not possible?

Comment: IIRC, you need to use AnimatorOverrideController.

Comment: @VenkatatAxiomStudios in the doc here (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorOverrideController.html) it doesnt mark that it has the functions i need (AddLayer, AddParameter,layers.Length,etc..)

Comment: I dont think you can do this man.Why do you want to load the controller from XML anyway ? you can load RuntimeAnimationControllers from the resource folder.